# Конвертировать PTYPE в Double

Tags: c++, qt

Написал код, однако он выводит такую ошибку:

```
C:\Works\contr_glsso1\mainwindow.cpp:771: ошибка: C2664: 'Line_Graph::Set_Data' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'PTYPE *' to 'double *'
 Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Не знаю, что делать. ;_;

defines.h

```
 typedef float PTYPE;
```

struct.h

```
 PTYPE *RE;
```

mainwindows.h

```
void Update_Line(double X);
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
void MainWindow::Update_Line(prof->RE)  // вот тут вот он выдает ошибку
```

Пытался привести к типу не вышло:

```
    void MainWindow::Update_Line((unsigned double *)prof->RE) // выдает ошибку C2664
```

Вот еще один вариант:

```
    void MainWindow::Update_Line(*prof->RE) // выдает  C2100: illegal indirection
```

И еще:

```
    double f1 = *prof->RE;
    void MainWindow::Update_Line(f1) // ошибка: C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Даже так пробовал:

```
  double f1 = *prof->RE;
    void MainWindow::Update_Line(f1) // ошибка: C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Конвертировать PTYPE в double не умею, от переменной отказаться не могу - много где используется. Код не мой, просто столкнулся с проблемой.

Comment: Тут вопрос не в том как привести одно к другому, а в том зачем вам это надо. `Update_Line` ожидает число с плавающей точкой. А вы ему передаете указатель на некий загадочный `PTYPE`.

Comment: покажите реализацию PTYPE

Comment: Приведите как минимум объявление `PTYPE`. А вообще - при такой постановке вопроса, даже если вам подскажут, как сделать, чтоб код **компилировался** - это еще не факт, что он будет **работать**. Например, можно просто написать `Update_Line(0.0);` :)

Comment: реализацию PTYPE добавил

Comment: Пробовали: `Update_Line(*prof->RE)`?

Comment: пробывал пишет C:\Works\contr_glsso1\mainwindow.cpp:772: ошибка: C2100: illegal indirection

Comment: @timob256 остаётся ошибка: `float f = *prof->RE;`?

Comment: @jfs чисто эта строчка "float f = *prof->RE;" компилируется без  вопросов, а вот когда её встраиваешь то уже снова ошибки.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [mcve], иначе догадки будут плодиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выложите весь код:

```
 void MainWindow::Update_Line(prof->RE)  // вот тут вот он выдает ошибку
```

Эта строчка и вызывает подозрение, там должно быть что-то типа:

```
 void MainWindow::Update_Line(double x);
```

А вот в месте, где её вызываете, может и нужны какие-то приведения типов.

Comment: я весьма упростил код, оставив саму суть, если  я выложу все то люди смотрящие его запутаются , этого бы не хотелось.

Answer (score 0):

При такой реализации

```
typedef float PTYPE;
PTYPE *RE;
```

`RE` - просто указатель на `float`, так что должно работать просто

```
Update_Line(*RE);
```

Но вы нам точно все рассказали? Зачем тогда вы пытаетесь так старательно получить `prof->RE`? Может, это поле в структуре? надо приводить всю информацию!

Если это поле в структуре, а `prof` - указатель на нее, то должно сработать

```
Update_Line(*prof->RE);
```

Раз не работает - давайте дополнительную информацию. Что такое `RE`, `prof` и так далее.
Ответ нужен вам - так почему из вас информацию по капле тянуть приходится?... :(

И еще - сообщение компилятора о функции `Line_Graph::Set_Data`, а вы нам старательно подсовываете `Update_Line`. Так все же, где ошибка?